# Graph is plotted wrong with pgfplots

Tags: plot

currently trying to make a graph with the forumla 0.5+(2x/3) but it does not seem to be correct? This is the code I am using (sorry if it looks bad :D)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={\texttt{Vatten hastighet från kant till mitt}},
            xlabel=$Meter från kant (m)$,
            ylabel={$v (m/s)$},
            xmin=0,
            xmax=3
    ] 
            \addplot[color=red] {0.5 + 2*x/3 };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

It is not correct, it should start at 0.5?

Comment: Try forcing ```ymin=0```

Comment: Just for the record: the plot was and is right. The ```0``` you see on the axis is only the origin of the x axis but not of the y axis. This is changed by the above setting.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that now, thank you again :-)

Comment: Don't mark questions with `[solved]`, this is not a forum. You can ask @bonanza to post an answer or post it yourself.

Comment: Also, don't write text in math mode, as you have done with the x label. If you want italics, use for example `\textit{...}`. Otherwise write `xlabel={Meter från kant (m)},ylabel={$v$ (m/s)}`.

Answer (score 4):

The plot is correct, in order to see the the origin include `ymin=0`, i.e.:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={\texttt{Vatten hastighet från kant till mitt}},
            xlabel=$Meter från kant (m)$,
            ylabel={$v (m/s)$},
            ymin=0,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=3
    ] 
            \addplot[color=red] {0.5 + 2*x/3 };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```